# How can I make a line behind a div not to show up on hover in css?

Tags: html, css

This is normal state, the line is behind the div

[image]

And this is hover state, the line shows up

[image]

Comment: here is the page online https://ahmetomerv.github.io/JobsBoard/

Comment: Share your code

Comment: here is the code https://github.com/ahmetomerv/JobsBoard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.listing` has a background transparency on `:hover`

The 0.17 in below css means it has an opacity of 17%; Change it to 1 and it will be opaque. You might want to change the actual hover color to something lighter though.

```
#timeline .listing:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #9fa3aa;
    background: rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.17);
}
```

Comment: Ah I can't belive it was because of the transparency of my background color.. ashamed :( thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In hover state, the div has a background where the alpha channel (which ranges from 0 = completely transparent to 1 = completely opaque) is set to 0.17, which is pretty transparent. Consequently, the line behind it shows up. It is not visible in the default state, because in the non-hover state the background definition for the div has no transparency.

Set

```
#timeline .listing:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #9fa3aa;
  background: rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.17); }
```

to

```
#timeline .listing:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #9fa3aa;
  background: rgba(217, 217, 217, 1.0); }
```

and the line behind the div should disappear, as it is "covered" by the div.